# How to automatically detect and output audio silence with FFmpeg (or SoX)?

Tags: ffmpeg, sox, noise-reduction

I have about 100 audio files that I want to run noise reduction on via SoX, but I don't want to manually create noise profiles for each one and I don't know with certainty that there are X number of seconds of silence at the beginning of each one, so I'm trying to figure out how to automatically detect silence in each file and save that silence to an audio file so that I can use that to create noise profiles with SoX. FFmpeg seems like it might be able to do this, but I'm not familiar with how it works. I've figured out that I can use silencedetect, but that just seems to give me timestamps. I'm not sure how I might use those as the input for something that would trim the audio to just those silent portions. I've also thought about silenceremove, but that does the opposite of what I want, i.e. I don't want to remove all the silence, I want to remove all the non-silence. Any suggestions?

Comment: "silence" in this case, I'm guessing, isn't perfect silence. Do you know or can you guess the volume level of these silent portions?

Comment: @Gyan Correct, not perfect silence. Sorry for not specifying that. I don't know the amplitude, but I would be able to guess. It should be similar for all the files, but the noise in the silent portions is not going to be identical.